# convex sets and a point outside

Tags: geometry

given a linear space, how can I show that for any convex set and an arbitary point which is outside the set, then we can find a hyperplane through the point such that the set exists on one side of the hyperplane?

Comment: Your issue deals with the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Peng.pdf).